# Direct image of finite morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In general, we know that the higher direct images of finite morphisms are zero.

Now, suppose we have a morphism $f: S\rightarrow B$ which is finite over a Zariski open subset (say $Z$) of the projective variety $B$. But, the fibers over the points of the complement of $Z$ are not finite.

In the above situation can we still say $Rf_* = f_*$?

Comment: No, in general $f_*$ is not exact for birational maps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f: X \to \mathbb A^2$ be the blow-up of the origin. $f$ is birational, hence satisfies your assumptions. Then $f_* = \Gamma(X,-)$. Clearly this functor is not exact, because $X$ is not affine (Serre's criterion for affine schemes). Thus there are non-zero higher direct images $R^if_*\mathcal F$ for some coherent sheaf $\mathcal F$ on $X$.

---

Since you want $f$ to map into something projective, just compose with the inclusion $U=\mathbb A^2 \hookrightarrow \mathbb P^2$. Then $\mathbb f_*(-)_{|U} = \Gamma(X,-)$ is not exact, hence $f_*$ is not exact.

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Comment: Same discussion is going on in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294515/higher-direct-image-and-finite-morphisms/294516?noredirect=1#comment731025_294516